# How to know whether a Spring Batch job is running for the 1st time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

**Requirement:**
A Spring batch (designed using Spring Boot) job is designed to take data from a database every 5 hours and is scheduled to run accordingly. **An added requirement is When the job will run for the very 1st time, it should fetch data of 4 months from the database.**

**Problem:**
How to know that the Spring Batch job is running for the 1st time. Is there any parameter in Spring Batch that can help us know whether its running for the 1st time.

Comment: spring batch stores job info in db. you can query to see if any job runs for a day yet. Take a look about Job Instance, Job Execution ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware Spring scheduler does not have a way to identify first time jobs(please comment/edit if im wrong). You can schedule two jobs, a single one time job that fetches data for 4 months and then the recurrant normal tasks in another job.